# Array sort NullpointerException

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections, nullpointerexception

I have a pretty easy for loop I need to use an array in but I need it sorted and finding that I get a NullpointerException when I know the array I am passing is populated.  I'm working with the Array.sort() means my int[] needs to be a generic and also thinking that I can convert to a list and use Collections sort but both seem to give me the error NullPointerException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int[] arrangedArray = null;
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int numberInputs = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        while(numberInputs>0) {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
            String[] arr1 = buffer.readLine().split(" ");
            Integer[] array1 = new Integer[size];
            for(int i = 0;i<size-1;i++) {
                System.out.println("Debug: " + arr1[i]);
                array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]);
            }
            arrangedArray = findMissingReapeatingFromArray(array1, size);
            numberInputs--;
        }
        for(int k =0;k<arrangedArray.length;k++) {
            System.out.print(arrangedArray[k] + " ");
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
} 
static int[] findMissingReapeatingFromArray(Integer[] number, int length) {
    List list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(number));
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
    System.out.println("Debug: " + set.size() + " " + number.length + " " + length);
    int[] array = new int[2];
    Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(number)); // the error is here stating my array is null
    //for loop to accomplish algorithm
    return array;
 }
```

**EDIT:**Added the main to see the input where the input shows all the elements are correct in the array that is being passed to the function without the null. The Debug for the findMissingRepeatingFromArray gives for the input

```
1
5
2 3 4 4 5
Debug: 2
Debug: 3
Debug: 4
Debug: 4
[2, 3, 4, 4, null]
```

My debug statement returns the correct return.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(number).toString());` and check if any elements of your array are `null`.

Comment: @PM 77-1 I have a null element in the array. I have another debug that shows in the input that it is correctly populated.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` method does not like nulls and throws NPE.

Comment: `for(int i = 0;i<size-1;i++)` **excludes** the last element and it remains `null`.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Getting the index for the algorithm solution right had me messing with the input so good catch. Thanks.

Comment: @PM77-1 post your comments as an answer

Comment: @Bohemian - OK, if you say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you have `null` values in your array.  Internally `Collections.sort()` uses `compareTo()` method that cannot be called on a `null`.

The reason for the `null` in your array is that you do not initialize its last element and it stays with its default value.

You have

```
for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
```

and it should've been

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

[index values from 0 to (size-1)]